# Pass only one value to php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn php and javascript by creating a portfolio of stocks. What I want to do is have the price cell of the table update automatically without refreshing the page by using javascript. I created a new php file to get only that price field to the portfolio but I cannot seem to get it to work. I get a lot of errors on that price field. I have put all the file here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NZ31hJPV) . Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

```
portfolio.php file

<table class="table table-hover center-table table-bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shares</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
<?php foreach ($shares as $row): ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?= $row["symbol"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["name"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["shares"]?></td>

        <td id="price">$<?= number_format($row["price"],2)?></td>

        <td>$<?= number_format($row["total"],2)?></td>
        </tr>

<? endforeach ?>



<tr>
    <td>CASH</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<?= number_format($cash[0]["cash"], 2)?></td>

</tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/update.js" ></script>
```

index.php file

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

//query user's portfolio

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$cash = query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    //create array to store the shares
    $shares = [];

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        //lookup stock info
        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);


        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = [
                "name" => $stock["name"],
                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "shares" => $row["shares"],
                "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]

            ];
                 //dump($shares);      
        }

    }

// render portfolio
render("portfolio.php", ["shares" => $shares,"cash" => $cash, "title" => "Portfolio"] );  
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php

require("../includes/functions.php"); 
require("../includes/config_update.php");

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$cash = query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
        //create array to store the shares
    $shares = [];

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);

        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = [

                "name" => $stock["name"],
                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "shares" => $row["shares"],
                "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]
            ];

        }
    }

// render portfolio
render("portfolio.php", ['shares' => $shares, 'cash' => $cash]);  
?>
```

update.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var updater = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#price').load('update.php', 'update=true');
    },6);
});
```

When I run this first I get the whole table in the price cell as well as these error messages Notice: Undefined variable: shares in portfolio.php line 10
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in portfolio.php on line 10
Undefined variable cash in portfolio.php on line 31

I do not get any errors anymore but now I get the whole page inside the price field in the table.

Comment: Please edit the question and post some code and any error messages you have.

Comment: Don't use external services like jsFiddle or pastebin to host your code. Code goes in the question, and then you may supplement your question with a working example.

Comment: Sorry about that. Posted the code with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an array of parameters in index.php, one of which has the key `shares`, however in update.php you're trying to just pass back that array, change this in update.php

```
 render("portfolio.php", $share);
```

to

```
render("portfolio.php", ['shares' => $share]);
```

Comment: When I do this I still get an error messages. Undefined index: symbol in portfolio.php on line 13 Undefined index: name in portfolio.php on line 14 I get the same thing for shares, total and cash.

Comment: You will, you're only returning `$row['price']` for each share in update.php. Either make it match the array you're returning in index.php or check if those values are set before attempting to use them in portfolio.php

Comment: I matched the array from index.php in update.php and now I do not get any error messages but I get the whole page inside the price cell in the table.